# R Error: Warning Message: Numerical expression has 1000 elements: only the first used

Tags: r

```
    lamda=5
    theta=1000
    size=1000
    N <- rpois(size,lambda)
    Y.new <- rexp(sum(N),1/theta)
    Y.adj <- pmin(pmax(Y.new-500,0))
    gg <- function(i) {sum(Y.adj[(1+sum(N[1:(i-1)])):(sum(N[1:i]))])}
```

My "gg" function works just fine for putting in individual values from the 1000 sample:

```
    gg(44)
    [1] 1611.536
    gg(145)
    [1] 407.7765
```

But when I attempt to create a matrix of all 1000 values of the gg function (which is what I need), I get:

```
    gg(1:1000)
    Warning messages:
    1: In 1:(i - 1) :
    numerical expression has 1000 elements: only the first used
    2: In 1:i : numerical expression has 1000 elements: only the first used
```

I was just wondering how to get by this issue. Thanks!

Comment: The argument of the gg function can only take one number.

Comment: I understand that, but I am looking for a way to display all the values of gg(j) from 1 to 1000, ie gg(1) , gg(2), gg(3), ... gg(999), gg(1000)

Comment: Try 'sapply(1:1000, gg)'

Comment: You, sir, are a life saver